# Conditional Sum of Absolute Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum values using absolute numbers from the "E" Column if the "G" row has the value "Income"

```
=SUMIF(ABS(E2:E5105),"=Income",G2:G5105)
```

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(E2:E5105)*(G2:G5105="Income"))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(G2:G5105="Income",ABS(E2:E5105)))`

Comment: FYI. The second one, depending on one's version will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode. @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

Three methods per screenshot/table below & [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98UW9eb7gaUNs2Bo3?e=e1Cbdx) for convenience:

| Method | Formulation | Advantage | Disadvantage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `=SUM(1*(G3:G7=J3)*ABS(E3:E7))` | Simple | Calc intensive |
| 2 | `=SUMPRODUCT(1*($G$3:$G$7=J3),ABS(E3:E7))` | Intuitive | As for 1 |
| 3 | `=SUM(FILTER(ABS(E3:E7),G3:G7=J3))` | Simple, quick | Office 365 dependency |

[image: Summary of 3 methods]